# Document Color Profile & Settings in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color

I have to edit pdf files.

The way I am doing it right now is that I am importing it page by page in Illustrator.

When I "Place" each page from the pdf file in a new document I get the following message(screensot).

The file will be printed in Europe. Is the color profile settings going to affect the colors when printed? What should I do in this case. The way I did it before was to just Click "OK" and just leave it like that.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 questions here one is will colors change the other is what to do.

Will colors change? Ok this is a hard question simpliy because language lets us down. So it really boils down to wether you consider same to be based on a measurement, perceptual input or numerical data! These all have an answer that is different answer abd in eitger case it depends on what conversion intent you are operating under. But i would say that this is a somewhat irrelevant question. I mean how do you even know what the original colors were?

What should you do? Well if you agree with the conversion intent of the document use then use the documents profile. Now the other option is to do a profile to profile conversion. Whatever you do dont press ok because discarding the profile makes no sense. (you should probably configure the other option to be convert)